# Make Method return Func<> instead of bool

Tags: c#, delegates

How can I refactor my method to make it return its bool expression as code and not as a bool directly. I need this for an EF Core query, so it really is important that the code is returned as a delegate.

```
private static bool AreNotNull(DateTime? dateTime1, DateTime? dateTime2) 
        => dateTime1 != null && dateTime2 != null;
```

Comment: No, if you need this for EF you need to return an expression, such as `Expression<Func<...>>`.

Comment: No I am assembling the Expressions and inside the expressions I am calling these Func<>

Comment: EF will choke if you pass it an expression which calls a delegate internally. Not surprisingly either, as it can't be expected to turn a compiled delegate into SQL

Comment: You can't call delegates from Entity Framework expressions that will be converted to SQL. You will need to use Expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
private static Func<bool> AreNotNull(DateTime? dateTime1, DateTime? dateTime2)
    => () => dateTime1 != null && dateTime2 != null;
```

Update:
As pointed out you need not evaluate everytime the method is called:

```
private static Func<bool> AreNotNull(DateTime? dateTime1, DateTime? dateTime2){
    var res = dateTime1 != null && dateTime2 != null
    return () => res;
}
```

Moreover if you want to filter a IQueryable ([cf.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-6.0#system-linq-queryable-where-1(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-boolean))))))) which you have to do if you e.g. want the database to make the filtering you need to return `Expression<Func<bool>>`:

```
private static Expression<Func<bool>> AreNotNull(DateTime? dateTime1, DateTime? dateTime2)
    => () => dateTime1 != null && dateTime2 != null;
```